# Regex matching string python

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to match the following string:

```
strings = iamcool.iplay=ball?end
```

I want to remove items starting (including the ".") and up till "?", so I want to remove `.iplay=ball`, so I should have `iamcool?end`

This is the regex I have:

```
print re.sub(r'\.\.*?','', strings)
```

I am not sure how to stop at the "?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use negated character class `[^?]` which matches anything except `?`.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\.[^?]*', '', strings)
'strings = iamcool?end'
```